# Efficiently collect data from multiple 1-D arrays in to a single 1-D array

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I've got a prewritten function in `C` that fills an 1-D array with data, e.g.

```
int myFunction(myData **arr,...);


myData *array;
int arraySize;
arraySize = myFunction(&arr, ...);
```

I would like to call the function `n` times in a row with slightly different parameters (`n` is dependent on user input), and I need all the data collected in a single `C` array afterwards. The size of the returned array is not always fixed. Oh, and `myFunction` does the memory allocation internally. I want to do this in a memory-efficient way, but using `realloc` in each iteration does not sound like a good idea.

I do have all the `C++` functionality available (the project is in `C++`, just using a `C` library), but using `std::vector` is no good because the collected data is later sent in to a function with a definition similar to:

```
void otherFunction(myData *data, int numData, ...);
```

Any ideas? Only things I can think of are `realloc` or using a `std::vector` and copying the data into an array afterwards, and those don't sound too promising.

Comment: `vector` is fine, as it stores the data contiguously and you can pass `data()` to a C-function.

Comment: From what I've read, I'm going to try with `std::vector::data()`, it looks like the simplest approach :)

Comment: @Kerrek SB I've tried using `std::vector::data()` function and it works perfectly with all the functions requiring `mydData *`. If you would write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think @larsmans already posted essentially the same, so you can just accept his answer if you like...

Comment: @KerrekSB Ok, I'll accept his answer but I'll add a mention of the `data()` function, since reading up on that was what was really usefull:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy all of the data into an `std::vector`. You can call `otherFunction` on a vector `v` with

```
otherFunction(&v[0], v.size(), ...)
```

or

```
otherFunction(v.data(), v.size(), ...)
```

As for your efficiency requirement: it looks to me like your optimizing prematurely. First try this option, then measure how fast it is and only look for other solutions if it's really too slow.

Answer (score 3):

Using `realloc()` in each iteration sounds like a very fine idea to me, for two reasons:

1. "does not sound like a good idea" is what people usually say when they have not established a performance requirement for their software, and they have not tested their software against the performance requirement to see if there is any need to improve it.
2. Instead of reallocating a new block each time, the `realloc` method will simply keep expanding your memory block which will presumably be at the top of the memory heap, so it won't be wasting any time either traversing memory block lists, or copying data around. This holds true provided that whatever memory allocated by `myFunction()` gets freed before it returns. You can verify it by looking at the pointer returned by `realloc()` and seeing that it always (or almost always(*1)) is the exact same pointer as the one you gave it to reallocate.

**EDIT** (*1) some C++ runtimes implement two heaps, one for small allocations and one for large allocations, so if your block gets allocated in the heap for small blocks, and then it grows large, there is a possibility that it will be moved once to the heap for large blocks. So, don't expect the pointer to always be the same; just most of the time.

Comment: Very true, but using `realloc` actually *is* a bad idea, since this is a C++ program. Using `std::vector` is a much better idea.

Comment: `realloc` *might* keep expanding. Or it might just copy it every time.

Comment: `realloc()` will _most probably_ keep expanding. In any case, I provided penelope with a means of verifying what realloc does. So, if it does not keep expanding, she can ditch the idea. But in any case, if she prefers `std::vector`, and she _can_ actually use `std::vector`, then I think that's a good idea, so I pass. I just spoke of `realloc` because I thought `std::vector` was not an option, because it would require modifying `MyFunction()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are going to call the function N times, and returned arrays are always M long, then why don't you just allocate one array M*N initially? Or if you don't know one of M or N, then set a worst case maximum.  Or are M and N both dependent on user-input?

Then, change how you call your user-input-getting function, such that the array pointer you pass it is actually an offset into that large array, so that it stores the data in the right location.  Then, next iteration, offset further, and call again.

Comment: I just edited my questions, neither N or M are known beforehand. And also, I can't change the input-getting function, since it is from a pre-existent `C` library (I'm not the author)

Answer (score -1):

I think best solution would be to write your own 1D array class with some methods which you need.

depending on how you write the class you'll get such result. (sorry bad grammar)..

Comment: thnx for the fast reply. Unfortunately, I can't use my own 1D array class - the functions I use are from an existent library, and they work only with `myData *` coupled with `int n`-the size of the data array. But even if I do write my own class, I still have to deal with the _same_ problem to deal with the class methods

Comment: There's no need to implement a 1-d array class. There's one in the standard library; it's called `std::vector`.